how to get historical table info like count of records 7days ago
My requirement is-
Fetch the count of a table, size of a table 7days ago.
Basically, right now, if I need current info, I use information_schema.tables. But this doesn't show what was the table stats 7days ago. I need the old count of a table.
There is no time travel on metadata views. Is there any way to get old info on information schem tables?
I can time travel and get the data from the table itself but I want to see if we can do this easier/faster using time travel or something else.

As far as I know, Snowflake doesn't provide history for table-level storage metrics.  I would recommend leveraging time-travel and create a new table from it.  Some Snowflake customers also take snapshots of account_usage tables for purposes of trending on things like this.  Doesn't help you now, but maybe moving forward it'd be something to consider.

Hmm, looks like that's the path we may have to take. Store those metadata tables daily in a new table and get historical stats from there. Thanks and pls keep me posted if you have something. Thank you for your time

As a note, it never hurts to make a request with Snowflake for a new view in Account Usage to provide table storage metrics daily.  I've run across the need for this to show "rapidly growing tables" myself.
